# Show Popup message after asp.net Ajax progress is completed

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to show a modalpopup as soon as my progress for sending email to the registering user and inserting all values in the database completed ... but i m not able to do so.

Comment: Add some code for better solution !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a modalpopup through jquery...

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="btnTarget_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" BehaviorID="PopUp"
 CancelControlID="idclose" drag="true" 
 DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="popuphrbody" 
 PopupDragHandleControlID="hrtitle" TargetControlID="btnTarget">
 </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Show your popup by using behaviourID of modal popup as follows..

```
if ($find('PopUp')) {

        $find('PopUp').show();

    }
```

Here `Popup` is the behaviourID of the modal popup...

If you want to show it on code behind..

```
btnTarget_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
```

Here `popuphrbody` is the body part of your popup and `hrtitle` is the title part...

Comment: @Jasmeen actually first of all i want to show progress bar and after that i want to show modalpopup with the enquiry id generated on registration of user

Comment: i am able to show only one thing either a progress bar or a modalpopup after completion of submission

Comment: Please add to the question how you are showing progress bar..So I can try to show modal popup,Regards...

Comment: Jasmeen Leave everything about progress bar... now i want to show a popup with a gif image and on submission i want to show some label on the same modalpopup and want to hide gif with visible property ...

Is it possible in any way??